# How can I prevent a div from resizing with the browser?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to not resize with the browser window. I can't set the width or give it a min-width because it does need to resize with its contents. I simply want it to ignore the browser size completely and size normally to its contents. Seems pretty simple but I've been searching for days and been unable to find a solution to this.

Any ideas? I'm looking for an html/css solution not javascript. I already have a javascript hack that works but I'd rather not do this.

Comment: Have you considered max-width?

Comment: The problem is that the div shrinks. Its max and min width aren't a problem. It sizes to its contents properly on a fullsize browser but the div shrinks as the browser does which I do not want.

Comment: You want the div to be larger than the window? Can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 0):

A div full of content won't be wider than the browser width by default unless, for example, there is an image in there that is wider. That will cause horizontal scroll. If you want it to be wider, you can give a width like 150%.